# Remove trailing whitespace for text files only in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

Everything I found online was about removing the trailing whitespace altogether but I'd like to remove it only for text files, in particular `.key` files.

I tried to modify the `config.cson` like this:

```
".text.plain.key":
  whitespace:
    removeTrailingWhitespace: true
```

or small variations of it, but I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If `text.plain.key` is a valid scope, the correct entry should look like this:

```
".text.plain.key":
  editor:
    removeTrailingWhitespace: true
```

Comment: Is `".text.plain.key"` on the same level as `"*"`? It should be, then it works perfectly (tested on Atom 1.28 on macOS and Windows 10)